# laravel return null after get

Tags: php, laravel, session, post

I have a function for post and in I want to add an array to a session and use that in other page.  But after one run it returns null:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
session::put("a",$arr);
$b = session::get("a");
...
session::put("a",$b);
dd($b);

=> [
0=> 1,
1=>2,
2=>3
]
```

Now in next send post I comment two first lines:

```
//$arr = [1,2,3];
//session::put("a",$arr);
$b = session::get("a");
...
session::put("a",$b);
dd($b);

=> null
```

Why is it returning a null?

Answer (score 1):

You can't store an array in a session.   You can do this with json_encode and json_decode.  Example:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
session::put("a",json_encode($arr));
$b = session::get("a");
```

Then, in the other page, you can do:

```
$b = json_decode(session::get("a"), true);
...
dd($b); // should print an array.
```

If you want an object intead an array, remove the second parameter: true, to json_decode.

Check these example in PHP Docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand about the lifecycle of the session in laravel. Based on your code, you tried to dump the data before the lifecycle finish. What you should do is just let the lifecycle finish first by return the response and then you can get the data on your next request by dump the data or return to a response, so you don't need to stop the lifecycle.

Comment: but I need get array amount from session and add new value in to that then put new array to session in one request.

Comment: Can you give more details about the changes that you do in one request? Because if you only need to do the changes in one request, you can put in the variable first and at the end of the request you can put the data in the session.